# How to select datetime mysql type as java.time.LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
CREATE TABLE `datetimetest` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `thedatetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `thetimestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
List<Map<String, Object>> generic = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM mytable);
```

Problem: both `datetime` and `timestamp` types are converted to `java.sql.Timestamp` by default.

Question: how can I tell the `JdbcTemplate` globally to convert any sql column of type `datetime` to `java.time.LocalDateTime` (because it has no timezone in the mysql database anyhow)?

Sidenote: I know it's possible to explicit parse the result set, like:

`rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class));`

But I'm looking for a global configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implementation of `RowMapper` when performing db calls (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html). If you want to use that globally, you can create a class that extends `JdbcTemplate` and overrides `getColumnMapRowMapper` in that class. Though that might need you to define it for all data types.

Another option which is what we use in my company is we have our own helper class that builds a query/rowmapper etc which is extended for each class that needs a DAO, and when called from the superclass that passes to `JdbcTemplate` all the relevant bits of information to make a data query as we need it to, including a `RowMapper` for that class so all the columns are the needed data types.

Comment: Another option I found, is you can create a class extending `JdbcUtils` and overriding `getResultSetValue` as that's what picks up the data types for the query. Though how you could use that every time you use `JdbcTemplate.query` I'm not too sure.